# Tools to check Android App's Data Consumption

Tags: android, performance-testing

I am setting up a automation framework to test my android app. I need a few tools which can be used for non-functional testing for the below:

1. Data Consumption
2. Memory Consumption

Answer (score 0):

I use 'android.net.TrafficStats' for Network and 'Runtime.getRuntime()' for Memory Consumption.